# asp.net navigation custom pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Web Site. I have created a new Web Form at the top level and access it with `NavigateUrl="~/ChangePassword.aspx"`.

However if I try to add a new Web Form inside the `CustomPages` folder I can't access it like this...Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look into the `web.config` file within the **DynamicData** folder

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" 
           type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="true" />
    </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
```

any *access to an .aspx file* will be redirected to a **HttpNotFoundHandler**!

Within *CustomPages* folder you may place your own - **customized** - dyanmic data template pages for any kind of entitySet.

Just *create a subFolder* with the name of an EntitySet and *within* this folder, create (or copy) *your new templates*.

Anyways - this new templated customized pages will be accessible only by your defined route(s) (eg: `new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx")`  )